# Subtraction of r.v. variances in a poorly formulated exercise

Tags: statistics, variance

[image]

As i understand it the exercise asks "what is the distribution of a r.v.$Z$ subtracted by a value for a mean". To me it makes sense that $Z$ would have a mean $µ_{n+1}-\bar{X_n}$, and as it happens that mean would be $0$. The variance of said r.v. should be the same as for all the others. However, my teacher's solution is:
[image]

Thus, he seems to think that $\bar{X_n}$ is a r.v. with a variance of $9/10*15^2$ because he subtracts the variances. But in that case:

*Would the variance not be $\frac{11}{10}*15^2$ as you cannot subtract variances but instead add them?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be the sum of the first $10$ candidates: $$X_n=\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i$$
This is the sum of $10$ independent Normal Random variables. So by standard principles of the sum of independent Normal Random variables, we have the distribution of $X_n$ is Normal with mean $\sum \mu=10 \cdot \mu$ and variance $\sum15^2=10 \cdot15^2$.

By the scaling property of the Normal distribution, we have:
$$\bar X_n=\frac 1nX_n$$

Then $\bar  X_n$ has a Normal distribution with mean $\frac 1{10}\cdot 10\cdot \mu=\mu$ and variance $\left( \frac 1{10} \right)^2\cdot10\cdot 15^2=\frac {15^2}{10}$

And by definition the distribution of $X_{n+1}$ is Normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $15^2$ as in the question.

So then again from the properties of the sum of $2$ Normal Random variables, we have the distribution of $X_{n+1}- \bar X_n$ is Normal with mean $\mu-\mu=0$ and variance $15^2+\frac {15^2}{10}=15^2(1+\frac 1{10})$. The variance comes fromt he fact that $X_{n+1}$ and $\bar X_n$ are independent since the sum of the first $10$ $X_i$ are independent from the $X_{n+1}$$^{th}$ observation.

So $X_{n+1}- \bar X_n$~$\mathcal N(0,\frac {11}{10}15^2)$

I have used the standard properties of Normal Random variables here. So I believe you are correct.

Please let me know if I can clarify!

Comment: Yes that all makes perfect sense to me. I find it confusing that the exercise uses the notation $\bar{X_n}$, i have only ever seen it in my class used to describe a mean as a specific value not a r.v.. Is that notation ever used to descibre a r.v.? I am assuming that the exercise text saying "Let $\bar{X_n}$ be the sample mean" is simply an error.

Comment: It is technically a sample mean, since the values have already been realised for the n candidates. It is a little confusing because the question assumes we have no data.

Comment: Have you heard of Bayesian Data Analysis?

Comment: I don't think i have.

Comment: In Bayesian Analysis, if we assume the data $X$ comes from a normal distribution, it is common to also assume the mean and variance of that normal distribution themselves follow some distribution! It gets really strange at times but it can be such that the mean has its own distribution.